# Does code that is equivalent but have different syntax run faster in certain cases?

Tags: python, syntax, big-o, list-comprehension

Does syntax change Big O? Or perhaps change the speed of how a program is processed? I am going to use python as an example.

If I had the list comprehension code:

```
new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]
```

Would it run any differently than:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    if filter(i):
        new_list.append(expressions(i))
```

Do these pieces of code have anything different in them? Would one be considered faster than the other? Why or why not?

Comment: I've answered this post *anyway* but your question wasn't really on-topic here; it could perhaps be migrated to Programmers, but you need to narrow it down a little. I'll see if I can edit it to improve a little.

Comment: OTOH, there probably is a duplicate on Programmers.SE for this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big-O says nothing about syntax choice in a programming language. It is only useful as a *tool* to compare algorithms.

Syntax choices can change the *fixed cost* of each iteration. Your specific sample has different fixed execution cost per iteration and so the speed of execution will differ.

In Python you could use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) to compare execution speed of two ways to implement the same algorithm, and you could use the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to analyse what bytecode will be executed for each alternative 'spelling', informing you how much work the Python interpreter will do for each iteration.

For the specific example, the list comprehension will be faster because it does less work in bytecode; the extra lookups of the `.append()` method in the second example as well as invoking it is what slows it down.

Comment: You mention fixed cost, but what exactly is that referring to? Workload in bytecode? Is there somewhere I can begin reading about this in more detail? Besides testing, are there general guidelines? I am just looking to get started here.

Comment: @ApathyBear: then start with a good solid grounding course in algorithm design; I enjoyed [this MIT lecture series](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/); there is an updated course at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/

Comment: @ApathyBear: in this context, the fixed cost is the time it takes to execute one iteration of the algorithm. Both implementations are O(N) algorithms, you'd compare that against algorithms that are not O(N) and know that asymptotically speaking the O(N) one will be faster or slower. The fixed cost of an iteration then doesn't play at all. Rather, when N is pushed into infinity, you'll *know* which algorithm will win because piddly little details such as how long one loop takes no longer matter at that scale.